# How can I see the controller class (which one is it) for a page URL?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, controllers

I need to find which controller is in charge of a URL

> http://127.0.0.1/mysite/index.php/sales/order/history/

I am working on a website, and I want to know which controller is controlling this URL. How can I do this? The **core/Mage/Sales/controllers/OrderController** is not controlling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/OrderController.php**

action method is

```
public function historyAction()
    { }
```

First you have to  find the `frontName` that are define in **etc/config.xml** for example your example `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml`.So url is work like  `baseurl/frontName/controllername/Actionmethod`

```
<frontend>
        <secure_url>
            <sales>/sales/</sales>
        </secure_url>
        <routers>
            <sales>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mage_Sales</module>
                    <frontName>sales</frontName>
                </args>
            </sales>
        </routers>
 </frontend>
```

sometime controller are overrides see these [example](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)

Comment: Thanks, I found another controller that is also controlling this same URL though. My question is how can I found ALL controllers that can handle this URL. Apparently Mage/Sales/controllers/OrderController.php controller is not in charge of this URL any more.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic i added explanation hope that will helpful for you

Comment: Ok, looks like the controller is infcat one that you mentioned. Probably something else was overiden, layout or template.